# Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10013N The specified library "GSKit Error: 207" could not be loaded. SQLSTATE=42724 SQLCODE=-10013

Tags: python, anaconda, db2, rhel

Trying to connect to an IBM DB2 on Cloud through a python script in an anaconda environment within a RHEL server and I am getting this error. Anyone have any advice?

As comment suggested here is my rhel version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.4 (Ootpa)

Using ibm_db v3.1.0 and ibm_db_sa v0.3.7

Here's my code:

```py
db2_db_dsn = 'DATABASE={};HOSTNAME={};PORT={};PROTOCOL=TCPIP;SECURITY=SSL;UID={};PWD={};'.format(
        creds['database'],
        creds['host'],
        creds['port'],
        creds['user'],
        creds['pw']

)

db_conn = db.connect(db2_db_dsn, "", "")
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add two facts. 1. The content of /etc/redhat-release, and  2. The text output of the db2level command located in the bin directory of your clidriver installation

Comment: Please add the db2level output.  Works fine for me at bash command line in rhel 8.5,  to db2 on cloud. Are you running the python In a notebook, or at the bash shell?  Learn to ask a good question,  by fully describing your  environment and how you run your code.